# Does $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ have a connected $T_2$ quotient?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Is there an equivalence relation $R$ on $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ such that $([0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q})/R$ is connected, Hausdorff, and has more than $1$ point?

Comment: Does $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ inherit the subspace topology from $[0,1]$ in the interval topology? If so, I believe this is the same as the rational interval $[0,1]$  in the interval topology.

Comment: @AlecRhea That's correct, $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ inherits the subspace topology from $[0,1]$ with the interval topology (or Euclidean topology, which is the same here).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there exists such a relation on $\mathbb Q$.

Just use the fact that the rational projective space $\mathbb QP^\infty$ from (the answer to) [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46986/countable-connected-hausdorff-space/285556#285556) is a countable, Hausdorff, connected (and even topologically homogeneous). By definition, the space $\mathbb QP^\infty$ is a quotient (and even open) image of a countable metrizable space without isolated points. By the classical Sierpinski theorem such space is homeomorphic to $\mathbb Q$ (and to $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$, too). So, $\mathbb QP^\infty$ is a connected Hausdorff quotient (even open) image of $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: " from (the answer to) this question" - not only in the answer, in the question itself too:)

Comment: @FedorPetrov Sorry. I had in mind that the notation $\mathbb QP^\infty$ appeared only in the answer but not in the question. That is why I wrote this way.